# Set up headless SSH with ethernet adapter for Pi Zero (Kali Linux)

Tags: usb, ethernet, kali

I have been doing some research about the Pi Zero, and have decided to try and make mine boot as an ethernet adapter. I have followed [this](https://jerrygamblin.com/2016/12/03/kalizero-a-pizero-usb-gadget-running-kali/) tutorial, but could not find a config.txt file. I added mine, and even after doing this, the Pi does not appear as an ethernet adapter...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you followed may simply be inappropriate for your situation, assuming that you installed Kali on a SD card. The tutorial apparently involves a regular Debian distro (that is, Raspbian), then adding the Kali tools (Katoolin). In other words, turning a Debian-like installation to a Kali-like installation...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but could you be able to provide an appropriate tutorial?

Comment: I found this: https://whitedome.com.au/re4son/sticky-fingers-kali-pi/ but not tested personally.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this as well, but it doesn't really help... Anyways, just going to set up another SD card with Raspbian, which is much easier to get running... Also, not as much apt-update and apt-upgrade to do...

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you didn't edit config.txt as needed. I really doubt that config.txt wasn't created after installation. I suggest trying to find that file again.

Comment: There was NO file. When I burned my image onto the SD card, on Windows, there was a `cmdline.txt` file, but no `config.txt` file...